# How do you create a child object with the constructor of parent object? (Java)

Tags: java, inheritance, composition

As an example, I have a `Car` class. When I create a car object I would like to pass the number of wheels I would like that car to have and the constructor would create `Wheel` objects from `1-x` number of wheel objects I passed to the `Car`'s constructor.

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

Parent is `Car`
Child is `Wheel`

Comment: take a look at what a `for-loop` is https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_for_loop.asp

Comment: Note that `Wheel` should certainly not be a parent of `Car`. (changes nothing about the logic)

Comment: thank you, sorry for the confusion the parent is the car and the child is the wheel

Comment: What do you mean by `1-x` wheel objects?

Comment: Thank you for the response @Raildex, my problem with the for-loop is that I can't figure out how to increment the object name of wheel.

Comment: That parent-child relationship is equally wrong. A `Wheel` is not a `Car`, simple as that. I cannot open the trunk of a wheel, put stuff in, get in the driver seat of the wheel and take off...

Comment: *"I can't figure out how to increment the object name of wheel"* then show us your current code / attempt.

Comment: @AmalK thank you for the response, I mean the person creating the car object would be able to pass any number of wheels they would like the car to have. so if they wanted a car with 6 wheels they could just go car(6); and it would create a car object and 6 wheel objects except they can put any number into car.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relationship of a car with its wheels is a **has a** relationship. A car has wheels. This being modelled through inheritance is semantically incorrect as inheritance is an **is a** relationship. A car **is not** a wheel. **Has a** relationship must be modelled through composition. A car contains multiple wheels. Use a collection like an array that holds the wheels for each car:

```
class Wheel {
        
}


class Car {
    // Use an array to hold the wheel objects
    private Wheel[] wheels;
    private String name;

    public Car(String name, int wheelCount) {
        this.name = name;
        wheels = new Wheel[wheelCount];
        for(int i = 0; i < wheelCount; i++) {
            wheels[i] = new Wheel();
        }
    }

    public void changeWheelAt(int index, Wheel wheel) {
        wheels[index] = wheel;
    }

    public Wheel getWheelAt(int index) {
        return wheels[index];
    }

    public Wheel[] getWheels() {
        return wheels;
    }
    
    
    public String getCarName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getNumberOfWheels() {
        return wheels.length;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope you do not actually mean that the Car class is the parent of Wheel. That would be an IS-A relationship. We do know that a wheel IS-NOT-A car.

What we might want to use here is the many-to-one composition (HAS-A) relationship between Wheel and Car. *Most cars HAVE wheels!*

So something like:-

```
public class Car {
      ...
      Set<Wheel> wheels;
}
```

Then you could have a constructor wherein you could pass the number of wheels and the set would be initialized.

```
public class Car {
      Car(int numOfWheels) {
        wheels = new HashSet<>();
        for(int i=0; i<numOfWheels; i++) {
           wheels.add(new Wheel());
           ... // Other Wheel properties
        }
      }
      ...
      Set<Wheel> wheels;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification it helped a lot :)